# SQL: How to select rows from a table while ignoring the duplicate field values?

Tags: sql, mysql

How to select rows from a table while ignoring the duplicate field values?

Here is an example:

```
id          user_id          message

1           Adam             "Adam is here."
2           Peter            "Hi there this is Peter."
3           Peter            "I am getting sick."
4           Josh             "Oh, snap. I'm on a boat!"
5           Tom              "This show is great."
6           Laura            "Textmate rocks."
```

What i want to achive is to select the recently active users from my db. Let's say i want to select the 5 recently active users. The problem is, that the following script selects Peter twice.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 ");
```

What i want is to skip the row when it gets again to Peter, and select the next result, in our case Adam. So i don't want to show my visitors that the recently active users were Laura, Tom, Josh, Peter, and Peter again. That does not make any sense, instead i want to show them this way: Laura, Tom, Josh, Peter, (skipping Peter) and Adam.

Is there an SQL command i can use for this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes. "DISTINCT".

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This won't work if he is trying to get the messages as well. `DISTINCT` discriminates based on all returned columns.

Comment: correct! But from the mention of names i'd say he wants the names. You can add it as a subquery for complete rows?

Comment: Thanks for the info coreyward. Great to know. What to use if i want to select the messages too?

Comment: Yes, this case I only wanted to select the names, since I want to know which users were recenlty active. Thanks Nanne.

Comment: But it would be great to know how to select the messages too at the same time? Any solutions?

Comment: Well, the problem is, what message would you want? You'll have to look at a heavier (even a GROUP BY, which feels like overkill) sollution. You'll have to use some sort of subquery probably

Comment: @Nanne I have same problem i want messages as well with unique user ID  (don't repeat ID)?? help ??? what is sub Query you are talking about ??

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could exclude duplicate user using `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: What are the differences between grounping and distinct?

Comment: `GROUP BY` will group all rows on a column. `DISTINCT` will filter out any rows where all of the returned columns are identical. In most cases, `GROUP BY` is faster. In this case, it'll also mean you can pull down the messages in the same query if you want to.

Comment: Grouping wil merge everything for that field. This means you should use an aggregate funciton on the other fields. AFAIK not very usefull for you situation

Comment: @coreyward I'm sorry, MySQL sux, in sybase doesn't work and in mysql really works, sorry about that. RTFM for me!